# How to use Azure OpenAI as a pseudo DB

Tags: azure

Someone asked me if they could use Azure OpenAI to create a DB from 1,000s or documents.

My first thought was that it couldn't, but then I started thinking it might be possible if we trained a model only using the data found within those 1000s of documents.

This model could be thought of as a pseudo DB where the user could "query" the db by asking the Model questions about the data it got trained on.

- ie. "What are the top 10 sales agents for North America for December?"
- ie. "Please list all conversations where someone mentioned that the coffee was cold."

My biggest fear is that this process would potentially generate phantom data or incorrectly return data.

##### Question.

Since I have never used Azure OpenAI I'm not sure if there are parameters that can be adjusted to mitigate this (phantom data or inaccurate aggregation of data) or if Azure Open AI has a different solution that would be more suited for this?

**Note**: All documents are structured similarly where the top portion includes a table with a key-value paring in each row followed by transcripts.

Comment: It depends on the document types (it only reads text) and what kind of information you want to get out of it. It's a natural language model, meaning it can chat with you using your documents as reference, but it's not going to read tables or calculate numbers. The two example questions you give are **not** something it could answer. They have a lab with examples on using your own data here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/use-own-data-azure-openai/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing sounds like creating a [custom GPT](https://openai.com/blog/introducing-gpts) which will answer questions based on data you add yourself.

Yes, you could use Azure OpenAI in this manner as you can see in the link above.

It's unclear whether you *should* use it this way. [Zapier's article](https://zapier.com/blog/custom-chatgpt/) on building a custom GPT suggests that a chatbot might not be accurate even when external data is uploaded.

> It's worth mentioning that my chatbot didn't consistently refer to the guide I uploaded to teach it how to write alternative text.

At the current time, there aren't any parameters that can be adjusted to mitigate this (phantom data or inaccurate aggregation of data), and Azure OpenAI does not have a different solution that would be more suited for this.

You cannot exclude all other data that chatgpt uses, because it is used to help chatgpt understand input and write answers ([how chatgpt works](https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/ChatGPT)).

If you're interested in trying out OpenAI in this manner, the article from Zapier above has detailed steps on how to do it. In summary, you would:

1. Use "Create a GPT" option in the paid version of ChatGPT.
2. Instruct it that you're creating a company reference GPT based on company documents.
3. Upload documents using the upload Knowledge function in the custom GPT configuration page.

Hope this helps!